# tensorflow: read a binary file with different types

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

In tensorflow's [cifar10 example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py), they use the following code to read an image from a [binary file](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html):

```
image_bytes = result.height * result.width * result.depth

record_bytes = label_bytes + image_bytes
reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=record_bytes)
result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Convert from a string to a vector of uint8 that is record_bytes long.
record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)
```

My problem is that I have a similar binary file but with different types (not like CIFAR10 where just the first byte is cast to `tf.int32`). A record (row) of my binary file looks something like:

```
<1 x label (binary)> TYPE * 100
```

where `TYPE` is

```
<1 x float8> < 500 x binary> <1 x float8> <100 x binary>
```

i.e. I have a binary label, followed by 100 times the previous sequence of bytes.

I tried using `tf.decode_raw` with a sequence of types like someone would do in numpy, but it doesn't accept a list or a tuple of types.

Any idea how to read my binary file directly in tensorflow? Or, any idea how to read *efficiently* records and put them in `placeholders` with a given shape?

Comment: hi! with binary you mean a single bit? so 801 bits per record? can you share a sample of your data to test on it? My first approach would be to try to convert your (boolean?) labels to float8 and then load them with an uniform type. This would be faster, and not much more memory-inefficient (from 801 to 808 bits per label, increase of less than 1%)

Comment: Yes, by binary I mean a single bit. As you can see, 'TYPE' contains hundreds of 'binary' values. Thus, converting everything to float8 would be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Right! my bad. I'm not aware of any TF native way to deal with this... let's hope some expert jumps in. I will keep an eye on the thread too, GL